# Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' : A UserDetailsService must be set

Tags: spring, spring-security

Creating a new project from scratch.
It has {springframework-version} 4.2.5, {spring-security-version} 4.2.5

I have been trying the various thread suggestion, not helpful!
Each problem has unique solution... so

***By the way, part error on the console is...***

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in com.myproject.config.SecurityConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set  

ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in com.myproject.config.SecurityConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set.  

.....
.....
at com.myproject.config.SecurityConfiguration.configureGlobal(SecurityConfiguration.java:28)
```

***Tomcat Log is...***

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [com/myproject/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5278)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProvider' defined in class path resource [com/stragure/webstat/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:380)
at com.stragure.webstat.config.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$85d504e8.authenticationProvider(<generated>)
at com.stragure.webstat.config.SecurityConfiguration.configureGlobal(SecurityConfiguration.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:654)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A UserDetailsService must be set
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.doAfterPropertiesSet(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:123)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 74 more
```

**My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class**

```
package com.myproject.config;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(loginService);
}

@Bean
protected AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(loginService);
    //daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity.csrf();
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("login").permitAll();
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

}
}
```

**My WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.myproject"})
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getNamedParamterJdbcTemplate(){
    return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webstat");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    return dataSource;
}

/*@Override
public void addResourchandler(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry){
    resourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler("/resources*//**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources");
}*/

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

**My AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class**

```
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{WebConfiguration.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[0];
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
}
```

**My UserDetailsService class**

```
@Service
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService{

LoginDao loginDao;

@Autowired
public void setLoginDao(LoginDao loginDao){
    this.loginDao = loginDao;
}
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String emailId) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserInfo userInfo = loginDao.findUserDetails(emailId);
    if (userInfo == null){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("This user doesn't exist");
    }
    List<String> userRoles = loginDao.getUserRole(emailId);
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorityList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if (userRoles != null){
        for (String role : userRoles){
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role);
            grantedAuthorityList.add(grantedAuthority);
        }
    }

    UserDetails userDetails = new User(userInfo.getFirst_name(), userInfo.getPassword(), grantedAuthorityList);
    return userDetails;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LoginService loginService` in `SecurityConfiguration` is null, so the `UserDetailsService` you're setting in your `DaoAuthenticationProvider` is null. Perhaps you wanted to `@Autowire` it into your configuration. If so, add `@Component` (or `@Service`) to your `LoginService`.

Comment: Where is your loginService coming from? It's never initialized or assigned a reference

Comment: yeah you were it was missing (along with some other silly mistake).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(loginService);
}
```

Are you missing an `@Autowired` on your `LoginService loginService;` declaration?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
LoginService loginService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception{
    authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(loginService);
}
```

Could be as simple as that!